# same result in number of rows in mysql with php

Tags: android, mysql

I work at android application that connect with database in server

I need to check log in by user name and password

If the user name and password found in database the user found

I add in table log in usernames and passwords but the result of code is no

```
    $name = $_POST["user_name"];

$password = $_POST["password"];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_name,password from login WHERE user_name = '$name' AND password = '$password'");
        $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        if ($no_of_rows == 1) {
          $json = array("result"=>"yes");
        } else {
          $json = array("result"=>"no");
        }


header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json)
```

I add in table login usernames and passwords but the result of code is no if username and password founded or not

what is the problem in this code ??

Comment: The MySQL query seems ok, but I can't see the mysql_connect nor the mysql_select_db statements. Please add them in your post.

Comment: there is no problem in mysql_connect or mysql_select_db because give result but the result always no

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to several reasons:

- The `mysql_query` is returning an error. I'd recommend to check the returning result with:

  `if ($result === FALSE)
    echo "I have an error in my MySQL sentence\n";`
- It's not mandatory, but I don't know whether you have more than one opened MySQL socket. That's why it's always a good idea to specify the link id to the `mysql_query` function, e.g.:

  `$mylink = mysql_connect($host, $login, $password);
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT ...", $mylink);`
- It's always a good idea to test the sentences you're testing in your code manually. So I'd put `echo "SELECT user_name,password from login WHERE user_name = '$name' AND password = '$password'\n";`, then copy it, manually connect to the MySQL server and execute it and see whether it's returning anything (in case it returns something, that means that the error is in the code).
- It's not a debugging tip, but I'd recommend always encrypting the passwords in the database. So when you insert a login in the database, instead of inserting `('$user', '$pass')`, better insert `('$user', MD5('$pass'))`, for a better security. For the `SELECT`s it's the same: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE login = '$user' AND pass = MD5('$pass')`.

Hope this helps!